# AttributeError while using timedelta: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, time

I have the following code in which am trying to read the time string and reduce the time by 8 hours and print in a human readable format but am running into below error. Can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this?

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
time_string = '2018-07-16T23:50:55+0000'

#Reduct 8 hours and print in human readable format
struct_time = time.strptime(time_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")
t = datetime.datetime(*struct_time[:6])
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
print(t+delta)
```

Error:

```
    t = datetime.datetime(*struct_time[:6])
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Comment: You either need to: `from datetime import datetime` then use `datetime(*...)`; **or** `import datetime` then use `datetime.datetime(*...)`. The module named `datetime` contains (amongst other things) a class named `datetime`, so you have to be aware of which of those names is currently in scope. You're currently trying to access `datetime.datetime.datetime` which doesn't exist, hence the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I already have `from datetime import datetime` in my code,why is it still complaining?

Comment: Read the error. It's complaining because, despite explicitly importing the class into the current scope as `datetime`, you're trying to instantiate it as if you'd imported the whole module as `datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `datetime` from `datetime`. Later in the code you using `datetime.datetime`, so that's giving you error.

You shoud just call `t = datetime(*struct_time[:6])`

or

just do `import datetime` and call it `t = datetime.datetime(*struct_time[:6])`

The correct program should look like:

```
import time
import datetime
time_string = '2018-07-16T23:50:55+0000'

#Reduct 8 hours and print in human readable format
struct_time = time.strptime(time_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")
t = datetime.datetime(*struct_time[:6])
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
print(t+delta)
```

Comment: Then it throws an error `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'` at line `delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=8)`

Comment: @kemosabee Just write `import datetime`, not `from datetime import datetime` and leave the code as it was. I updated my answer

Comment: the time delta is increasing the time by 8 hours ,I want to reduce by 8 hours,how can this be done/

Comment: @kemosabee ...subtract it instead of adding it?!